# Vim: How do you open another [No Name] buffer like the one on startup?

Tags: vim

In my Vimscript program, I need to open an additional Vim buffer that is not immediately associated with a file, but which the user can save to a file of her/his choosing, just like the initial buffer called `[No Name]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 379, accepted):

There are many ways to open a new buffer with no name, the simplest of which is `:new`.

`:new` will create a split window with an unnamed buffer.

`:enew` will open one in the current window.

`:vnew` will open one in a vertically split window.

`:tabnew` will open one in a new tab.

Comment: How about a new buffer in the same way that `:e filename` opens buffers?

Comment: @minseong: I would also like to know the answer, asked a follow-up [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26805/how-to-open-two-new-empty-buffers).

Answer (score 7):

You may also want to look into <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> `filename`

I use split pane all of the time - it's pretty great.  In combination with screen you've got a lot of niceties there.

Answer (score 5):

In normal mode, type `:new<CR>`.